# How to get the status from json result set?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to get the cs field from the below json response. I tried with below code but I was getting an error

// json

```json
{
  "result": {
    "id": "3hQFg3kBhk_TTrQvcd6R",
    "percentage": false,
    "cd": "PROMO1",
    "ct": "Value",
    "va": 100,
    "cs": "Ready"
  }
}
```

// code

```java
Response response = getCoupon("3hQFg3kBhk_TTrQvcd6R");
Object result = response.getResult();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Coupon coupon = mapper.convertValue(result, new TypeReference<Coupon>() {});
System.out.println("coupon=" + coupon.getCouponStatus();
```

// error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "percentage" (class com.palmtree.matrimony.model.invoice.Coupon), not marked as ignorable (13 known properties: "cd", "kby", "mby", "en", "va", "cs", "ct", "cdt", "id", "mdt", "ed", "pr", "sd"])
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.palmtree.matrimony.model.invoice.Coupon["percentage"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:4236)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:4177)
    at com.palmtree.matrimony.integration.CouponIntegrationTest.readyCoupon(CouponIntegrationTest.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
```

Comment: so what's the error? post stack trace

Comment: @ShamithaSilva Posted

Comment: Can you post your `Coupon` class?

Comment: @VaibS All thanks for  your help, My problem resolved I have rewritten response class

Answer (score 0):

add `percentage` field to your `Coupon` class or mark it as ignorable...

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "percentage" })
public class Coupon {

//....

}
```

[Jackson ignore properties](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization)